# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog

Hello I have used OpenFileDialog in WPF for opening file, when I used first time it will work fine but when I clicked again it will give me error like 
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"
my code is look like

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;


    OpenFileDialog oldg = new OpenFileDialog();

    oldg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    oldg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    oldg.Multiselect = true;

    oldg.ShowDialog();
    string file = oldg.FileName;
```

please help me out this.

Comment: Where do you call that code? In an event handler of a button?

Comment: Where exactly occurs the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you're trying to use the [Windows Forms version of the `OpenFileDialog` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) in a WPF application.  You may have more luck using the [WPF version of the control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) instead.

In other words, try replacing

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

with

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```